# Quick way to tell what objects NSArray contains

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently working with someone else code, so i have a question is there a way to quickly tell what objects i have in NSArray.

In code i have for example:

```
Someclassobj.arr
```

And i know there is an array as a property in Someclassobj and of course i can see the definition of it, but still dont know what objects are inside. Could be NSString, NSDictionary,ObjectDefinedByUSer... How to quicly tell?

There is a method to check classes? If i execute:

```
id someUnknownObj = [Someclassobj.arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

How to check it? (i know isKindOfClass isMemberOfClass methods, but its doesn't work for me).

Of course there is **doesn't** have to be code method, could be something like option+click.

Comment: You can use NSStringFromClass([Someclassobj.arr  class]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will do the trick:

```
NSLog(@"%@",yourArray);
```

If you want to avoid this kind of stuff:

1) Put a breakpoint as soon as the `NSArray` has the objects.

2) Go to the Console on Xcode and do:

```
po yourArray
```

A great article about using the console in Xcode [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html).

Comment: This is a good answer.  I would add that you can get the name using `NSString *nameOfClass = NSStringFromClass([theObject class]);` if you want the name of it.

Comment: Oh, how simple is that ;) that is enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: I advise you reading the article, it can give you a considerable boost while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

you can do stk like this :

```
NSArray *arr; // Array with random stuff
for (id elt in arr) {
   if ([elf iskindOfClass:[NSString class]])
       NSLog(@"Object = NSString);"
}
```